# Route URL must be started with '/'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've declared Index action in Home controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string type)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
   {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", new { type = "promotion" });
   }
   return View();
}
```

That accepts:

```
https://localhost:44300/home/index?type=promotion
```

and

```
https://localhost:44300/?type=promotion
```

Everything was ok until I config route for 404 page:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "homepage",
        url: "home/index",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        url: "/",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
    routes.MapRoute(
        "404-PageNotFound",
        "{*url}",
        new { controller = "Error", action = "PageNotFound" }
    );
```

Invalid syntax:

> The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot
>   contain a '?' character.

If I remove the second configuration,

```
https://localhost:44300/?type=promotion
```

wouldn't be accepted. -> Show 404 page.

My question is: Is there a way to config route URL start with '/' (none controller, none action)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15163043/the-route-url-cannot-start-with-a-or-character-and-it-cannot-contain-a)

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl Have you read my question clearly?

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl Not duplicate. Pleae re-open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The route template separator character '/' cannot appear consecutively - Attribute routing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152847/the-route-template-separator-character-cannot-appear-consecutively-attribu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is misconfigured, as the error states it cannot begin with a `/`, and for the home page it doesn't need to. In that case it should be an empty string.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

However, it is a bit unusual (and not SEO friendly) to want to map more than one route to the home page of the site as you are doing.

It is also unusual to do a redirect to a home page, which does an additional round trip across the network. Usually routing directly to the page you want will suffice without this unnecessary round trip.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "homepage",
    url: "home/index",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", type = "promotion" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    url: "/",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", type = "promotion" }
);

// and your action...
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(string type)
{
   return View();
}
```

Comment: Sorry for this but the url really starts with '/' when I call `/?type=promotion` as you can see above. I have no idea about `url: ""`. That's help