# The route template separator character '/' cannot appear consecutively when adding action to default route

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I have a Web API 2 project hosted through an OWIN middleware. Everything worked perfectly fine and I am able to call my APIs as expected. But, my WebApiConfig defines the default route as follows:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Accordingly, I have to call my APIs using URLs similar to: `/api/values/dosomething`

This worked for me until I decided to document my API. For that, I first tried using the [WebAPI Help Page package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage/) which did not work. Then I thought I should try [Swashbuckle Swagger](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) and see if that helps me avoid the problem altogether, but unfortunately, in both cases I got the same error:

> The route template separator character '/' cannot appear
>   consecutively. It must be separated by either a parameter or a literal
>   value. Parameter name: routeTemplate

After trying a few things, it turned out that when change the route template and remove the `{action}` part, the error is gone. But, I cannot really do that because the whole project assumes that URLs include the action method name in them.

So anyway, I would like to know the following:

1. Why is this happening in the first place?
2. Is there a way to modify this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30152847/the-route-template-separator-character-cannot-appear-consecutively-attribu

Answer (score 6):

I fetch the same problem. Below is my working code.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/User")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("login")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {       }
}
```

when I change  Route before methods from

```
[Route("login")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{       }
```

to

```
[Route("/login")]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{       }
```

I got same error.
 It will generate if you add an extra **`/`** before any methods of your controller(if it is not called at first time).

I am not sure about your condition. I share my situation if anyone gets help.

Comment: had this same issue and this answer fixed it for me